# Error CS7036 No se ha dado ningún argumento que corresponda al parámetro formal requerido

Tags: c#, visual-studio, eventos, visual, timer

Buen día, alguien por favor me podría ayudar con este error que me sale al llamar un método al iniciar un formulario. Quedo atento, muchas gracias.

**Aquí trato de llamar al método:**

```
 public OrdenesTrabajo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1_Tick();
        }
```

**Este es el método que quiero llamar:**

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: si te das cuenta tienes 2 argumentos más que pide tu método timer1_tick, que no le estás pasando.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a ponerle: timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e);? Así tampoco me funciona.

Comment: sí y no, object sender y eventargs e son parámetros que está esperando tu formulario, déjame busco la forma de llamarlo y te hago una respuesta

Comment: Está bien, muchas gracias. Quedo atento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu método tienes 2 parámrtros necesarios para ejecutarlo:

1. object sender: El objeto que envía la acción
2. EventArgs e: (copiado
   de la documentación de esa clase) Representa la clase base para las
   clases que contienen datos de eventos, y proporciona un valor a
   utilizar para los eventos que no incluyen datos de eventos.

**si tu no pasas esos parámetros, el método siempre te mostrará un error.**
Ahora...

¿Cómo lo puedo usar si necesita esos dos parámetros?

Sencillo, el objeto que envía la acción es tu formlario, así que podemos utilizar la palabra reservada `this`, y respecto a el `EventArgs`, puedes crear uno nuevo que esté vacío para el caso específico que estás manejando en este momento. tú código quedaría así:

```
 public OrdenesTrabajo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1_Tick(this,  new EventArgs());
        }
```

como dato adicional, no se me hace muy buena idea que llames a métodos de componentes de tu formulario, considera el crear un método que contenga lo que vas a utilizar de él y sólo tendrías que llamarlo.
Espero que la respuesta te sea útil, ¡saludos! :D